# Do activated hoppers produce less lag than unactivated hoppers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I know that putting blocks with containers above hoppers can reduce the calculations that the game needs to run, improving the performance of the game.

Does activating hoppers with a Redstone signal (thus locking them) achieve a simillar effect?

Comment: Furnaces on top of hoppers no longer help: https://youtu.be/JdxaIIwdVm4 But locking them should help, unless the game is very badly programmed (which it is in parts, so maybe it doesn't help). But it would also make the hoppers basically useless. What setup do you have where this is an option?

Comment: I'm building a 16 furnace smelting array in a server (so 32 hoppers in total, all with rails on top), and I'd rather spare the server as much lag as possible. So my idea was to lock the hoppers when the furnace isn't being used, but I don't know if it will make any meaningful difference in performance.

Comment: 32 hoppers don't make any meaningful difference in performance, locked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do. Here is the performance graph after I put a redstone block under each hopper using `/fill`:

[image]

The bottom right graph shows how many milliseconds each server tick takes, with longer lines being more time. You can clearly see the drop when I deactivated all 32761 hoppers.

In this test all hoppers were facing down, I deactivated them with redstone blocks below and I used a render distance of 32.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I think so...

I watched a video where they experimented with this and if I remember correctly the answer is yes. If a hopper is activated (powered by Redstone) it doesn't need to check the blocks around it, if it has an input or output.

Comment: Hello! Can you link the video here and explain how you obtained the answer from the video?

Comment: here is the video i watched   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yINcXy-ajiU